# Run websocket in web worker or service worker - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, service-worker, web-worker

I have 9 websocket connections from different sites working to update the DOM with data. Currently I am connecting to all and listening to all websockets and updating the data with a function call.

The issue I'm facing is that there are many websocket connections and there are memory and CPU usage issues. How can I use either service workers and web workers to optimize so many websocket connections?

```js
async function appendGatePublicTickersData(e) {
  if (e.event == "update" && e.result[0].contract == "BTC_USD") {
    if ('total_size' in e.result[0]) {
      $(".gate-btc-open-interest").html(commaNumber(e.result[0].total_size))
      if ('last' in e.result[0]) {
        $(".gate-btc-open-value").html(commaNumber(customFixedRounding((e.result[0].total_size / e.result[0].last), 4)))
      }
    }

    if ('volume_24h_usd' in e.result[0]) {
      $(".gate-btc-24-volume").html(commaNumber(e.result[0].volume_24h_usd))
    }

    if ('volume_24h_btc' in e.result[0]) {
      $(".gate-btc-24-turnover").html(commaNumber(e.result[0].volume_24h_btc))
    }

    if ('funding_rate' in e.result[0]) {
      var fundingRateBtcGate = customFixedRounding(e.result[0].funding_rate * 100, 4)
      $(".public-gate-btc-funding").html(fundingRateBtcGate)
    }

    if ('funding_rate_indicative' in e.result[0]) {
      var predictedRateBtcGate = customFixedRounding(e.result[0].funding_rate_indicative * 100, 4)
      $(".public-gate-btc-predicted").html(predictedRateBtcGate)
    }
  }
}

var pubGateWs = new WebSocket("wss://fx-ws.gateio.ws/v4/ws/btc");

pubGateWs.addEventListener("open", function() {
  pubGateWs.send(JSON.stringify({
    "time": 123456,
    "channel": "futures.tickers",
    "event": "subscribe",
    "payload": ["BTC_USD", "ETH_USD"]
  }))
});

pubGateWs.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  e = JSON.parse(e.data)
  appendGatePublicTickersData(e)
});

pubGateWs.addEventListener("close", function() {});
```

Comment: Moving the sending and receiving data part in a Web Worker might improve the performance on that end. Is the bottleneck in the data transfers or in updating the DOM?

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I connect to all websockets, the CPU and RAM usage increases significantly. How do I move the websocket to Web Worker?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since you are using Web Sockets it would be a good idea to use a [`SharedWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) to create a new thread for your Web Sockets. The difference between a normal `WebWorker` and a `SharedWorker` is that the web worker will create a new session in each tab or browser when loading the page, whereas the shared worker will use the same session in each tab. So all of your tabs or windows will have the same worker and same Web Socket connection to work with.

If the data is updated very frequently (more than 60 times per second) and the DOM has to be updated every time that happens, then use the [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method to throttle the amount that the DOM is being updated. It will wait for the next repaint cycle before updating the DOM with new content, which is about 60 times per second, or 60FPS.

An implementation of this would like the example below:

### Main thread.

```js
// Create shared worker.
const webSocketWorker = new SharedWorker('web-sockets-worker.js');

/**
 * Sends a message to the worker and passes that to the Web Socket.
 * @param {any} message 
 */
const sendMessageToSocket = message => {
  webSocketWorker.port.postMessage({ 
    action: 'send', 
    value: message,
  });
};

// Event to listen for incoming data from the worker and update the DOM.
webSocketWorker.port.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    appendGatePublicTickersData(data);
  });
});
  
// Initialize the port connection.
webSocketWorker.port.start();

// Remove the current worker port from the connected ports list.
// This way your connectedPorts list stays true to the actual connected ports, 
// as they array won't get automatically updated when a port is disconnected.
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  webSocketWorker.port.postMessage({ 
    action: 'unload', 
    value: null,
  });

  webSocketWorker.port.close();
});
```

### Shared Worker.

```js
/**
 * Set to store all the connected ports in.
 */
const connectedPorts = new Set();

// Create socket instance.
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://fx-ws.gateio.ws/v4/ws/btc");

// Send initial package on open.
socket.addEventListener('open', () => {
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    "time": 123456,
    "channel": "futures.tickers",
    "event": "subscribe",
    "payload": ["BTC_USD", "ETH_USD"]
  });

  socket.send(data);
});

// Send data from socket to all open tabs.
socket.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(data);
  connectedPorts.forEach(port => port.postMessage(payload));
});

/**
 * When a new thread is connected to the shared worker,
 * start listening for messages from the new thread.
 */
self.addEventListener('connect', ({ ports }) => {
  const port = ports[0];

  // Add this new port to the list of connected ports.
  connectedPorts.add(port);

  /**
   * Receive data from main thread and determine which
   * actions it should take based on the received data.
   */
  port.addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
    const { action, value } = data;

    // Send message to socket.
    if (action === 'send') {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(value));

    // Remove port from connected ports list.
    } else if (action === 'unload') {
      connectedPorts.delete(port);
    }
  });

  // Start the port broadcasting.
  port.start();
});
```

Sidenote: your `appendGatePublicTickersData` does not use the `await` keyword, so it does not have to be an `async` function.

---

Now supported since Safari 16.
[Browser support for Shared Web Workers](https://caniuse.com/sharedworkers)

Comment: This works fine. Thank you. How do I add a new websocket connection and listener to the same code? Do I have to create a new shared worker for the second connection or do I listen to that on a different port?

Comment: Well, that is up to you. You can either make multiple WS connections in the same worker, spread them over multiple workers or even let your shared worker create more workers which will funnel all the received data to a single shared worker, which in turn will send it back to the main thread from a single point. But it should all be in favor of performance. Only you can find out which works well enough for your case.

Comment: The description doesn't match the code. Even though you're using a shared worker, you're creating a new WebSocket in the `connect` event, so that's using one WebSocket per browser tab, not one per origin. To do it per origin, you need to start the WebSocket outside of the `connect` event, and then maintain an array of connected ports and call `postMessage` for each of them.

Comment: @whitehat101 you are absolutely correct. I've modified the answer to incorporate your suggested methods. This should use a single WS connection for all tabs on the same domain.

Comment: sharedWorkers are once again fully supported on Safari.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone well, [not yet](https://caniuse.com/sharedworkers), but [it's coming](https://webkit.org/status/#feature-shared-web-workers).

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, interesting. I'm almost certain I checked caniuse a while back on it, but maybe things have changed since 15.4 went GA. I also read this: https://itnext.io/safari-now-fully-supports-sharedworkers-534733b56b4c

Comment: @LarryMaccherone Support for Safari has dropped 2 days ago!

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I've been using the developer preview to test while I develop my app, but now I can go GA on Safari with it.